# log4j could not create log file in spring boot resti api

Tags: java, spring-boot, log4j

I created Spring boot application and also created logger using log4j.
I have tried everything possible, but still I am not able to generate a log file. It only prints to console

here my log4j.properties

```
 log=/home/jayanes/projects/HSS/server/logs
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file ,stdout
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=${log}/process.log
log4j.appender.file.Append=true
log4j.appender.file.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n




log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Can You help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the following dependency in your `pom.xml` then `spring-boot` will use its own default logging (logback) which is embedded within this dependency (you can check in your IDE on `dependency hierarchy` tab):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

In order to disable the default logging you need to exclude it:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <!-- Need to exclude spring boot's default logger in order to use log4j -->
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

After adding this in your `pom.xml` you will be able to see the logs from `log4j` if you have configured it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I tried several ways finally i found the solution

added `import org.apache.log4j.BasicConfigurator;` library manually and called that library in application run file

```
  BasicConfigurator.configure();
```

After added this configuration log files were created our desire file location

Thank you